# How to use umlauts with ruby's URI library

Tags: ruby, unicode, uri

Here is the problem: Ruby's URI library does not deal with umlauts; i.e.

```
irb> require "uri"
irb* URI("http://abc.de/äöü")
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://abc.de/äöü
```

How can I deal with that? This is Ruby 1.9.2, btw.

Comment: This happens with other unicode characters, not just those with umlauts.

Comment: The library's right, these characters are illegal in uris. You should escape them.

Comment: Browsers can deal with umlauts in URLs just fine; how do I what the browser does?

Comment: Browsers are too forgiving. RFC is not.

Comment: That is an [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier), not a URI. and as wikipedia says, URIs are limited to a subset of ASCII.

Comment: @radiospiel Browser's "deal with it" by silently converting it to an encoded URL, which is what they actually send.

Comment: Did you try simply to encode it first? `encoded_url = URI.encode(url)`

Comment: @tokland: Does this really work? You might be right; but what others are saying here - like that this is not an URI to begin with - also sounds true to my ears.

Comment: @radiospiel: that's the precisely the point, it's not a valid URL and therefore it must be encoded. If you write in a browser a URL with UTF8 chars they get converted automatically, right? I'd expect the same from a Ruby script without forcing the caller to do that encoding.

Comment: @tokland: would you say that URI.escape replaces the need for the Adressable gem then? If so, just make yours an answer to collect points :)

Comment: I have always used `URI.escape`, but as nobody mentioned it I was wondering if there was a problem with it. Anyway, when such a simple task needs an external gem I'd be suspicious :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Call [URI.encode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-encode) before parsing:

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI(URI.encode("http://abc.de/äöü"))
```

As a side note, be aware that if the URL contains a hash fragment (*#something*), you'll have to manually split it:

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI(URI.encode('http://example.com/page.html') + '#' + URI.encode('anchor'))
```

Comment: This is awesome! I totally didn't want to use Addressable and here it is, a valid solution with URI.

Answer (score 5):

The [Addressable](http://rubygems.org/gems/addressable) gem is what you want to use to deal with IRIs.

Comment: Then, you should probably accept the answer so others can know and so Sean can get some gnarly new reputation points.  :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought by upvoting the answer I would accept it automatically. This is fixed now, and I hope I remember that the next time ;)